# Write textbox.Text to another form

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, textbox

I am trying to get the value of a text box in another form to write to a .csv file. Currently I have a "logon" form which references a local database, then after successful login, they are able to enter data that is recorded to a .csv file. I would like to also include the "logged on user" and the best way I could think of was just grabbing the value of the text box on the first form. Is there a simple way to do this? I have tried

```
string currentUser = Form2.textBox1.Text;
```

But this returns "Form2.textBox1 is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Thanks!

Comment: In form2 design, change the "Modifiers" property to "internal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with a combination of your answers. I figured I'd post it here. Thanks for all your help! Added comments to show what I ended up adding.

```
"LOGIN FORM" 

Namespace Project1

    public partial class AuthenicationForm : Form
    {
        public AuthenicationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Added currentUser
        public static string currentUser;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"blahbalhbalhablh");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(blahblahblah);
            SqlDataReader sqldr;
            sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (sqldr.Read())
            {
                count += 1;
            }
            if(count == 1)
            {
                //Grabbed textBox text on buttonclick after filled out
                currentUser = textBox1.Text;
                this.Hide();
                Form1 ss = new Form1();
                ss.Show();
            }

"Recorder Form"

namespace Project1
{
    public partial class RecordForm: Form
    {
        public string newFile = "Place to save" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".csv"; 
        public RecordForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var UPC = textBox1.Text;
            var APCUPC = "00000";
            if (UPC.Length == 9 && UPC.Contains(APCUPC))
            {
                //grabbed the currentUser from the previous form
                File.AppendAllText(newFile, LoginForm.currentUser + "," + UPC + "," + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                this.label1.Text = "Scan successful, continue!";
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                this.label1.Text = "Scan unsuccessful, try again!";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying this is the right way to do this, but you could just change the `TextBox` to public.  Then you will be able to access it in another place.  A cleaner way would be to add a public property to your form called `UserName`.  I would also recommend changing the name of `Form2` to `LogonForm` and the `TextBox` from `textBox1` to `UserNameText` or something more meaningful than `textBox1`.

```
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}

// Then you can use it like this (where Form2 is an instance of the logon form)
string currentUser = Form2.UserName;
```

Remember, you will need the instance of the logon form.  Looking at the code in your question, it almost looks like you are trying to access the value of the textbox statically.

Comment: Thanks, I added that into my first form, but how would I access from my second form?

Comment: pstrjds, thanks for helping. I am close here, its just I need to do this I believe inside the button click on the logon form, since there is nothing recorded before the button click.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public property to read/write the TextBox Content on Form2:

```
public class Form2
{
    public string User
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the text of textBox1 via `form2.User`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I would normally create a global class `Session` where I would store the logged user information (session info) and later retrieve the information when required.

On logon:

```
//...
Session.LoggedUser = user; // Adapt it for your use case
//...
```

And finally in you Form2:

```
string currentUser = Session.LoggedUser;
```

If you want my personal opinion, I will at all time avoid making private control in one form public to another one. However, there are some cases where I actually do so. I will let you decide on the 2 method I proposed. ;)